# Where is the app defined in connect.js source?

Tags: node.js, node.js-connect

when read the connect.js source, I can not understand this line code:

```
function app(req, res, next){ app.handle(req, res, next); }
```

the question is : where is the `app` defined ?  `app.handle(req, res, next);`

https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/blob/master/lib/connect.js#L28

Answer (score 0):

`app` is defined in the `proto.js`: https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/blob/45fe02dde8b1f1da0dde0c593038753714f1d99b/lib/proto.js#L87

In JavaScript, functions are objects that do have properties. In the line below the `app` definition, they merge the properties from `proto.js` using [utils-merge](https://www.npmjs.com/package/utils-merge):

```
merge(app, proto);
```

Answer (score 0):

`app` is defined in the first line with `function app(....`.

However, `app` is expanded by `merge`-ing the `proto` module using [util-merge](https://github.com/jaredhanson/utils-merge) via the line `merge(app,proto)`.

Also note the merge with `EventEmitter.prototype` as that's also important.

Look at the `proto.js` file that is in the same directory as `connect.js` and you'll see the full `app` object that is exported.

```
function createServer() {
  function app(req, res, next){ app.handle(req, res, next); }
  merge(app, proto);
  merge(app, EventEmitter.prototype);
  app.route = '/';
  app.stack = [];
  return app;
}
```

Comment: Thanks,  I think using `proto.app` is more clear in this line.

Answer (score 0):

```
function app(req, res, next){ app.handle(req, res, next); }
//       ^^^                  ^^^
```

It’s defined right there.
The `handle` function is added to `app` later (defined in the [proto.js](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/blob/master/lib/proto.js#L87) file), using `merge(app, proto)`.

Here’s a simpler example of what the code does:

```
function dog () {
    dog.bark();
};

dog.bark = function () {
    console.log('Woof!');
};

dog();
```